# Unbiased estimation of variance of autocorrelated time series

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, bias

Let's say I have $n$ measurements (let's assume monthly measurements) of some underlying random variable $X_{t}$ for $t\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Now, let's say I then construct a new measure

$$Y_{t}=\tfrac{1}{12}\big(X_{t}+X_{t+1}+\cdots+X_{t+11}\big)$$
which is the forward 12-month average of the underlying random variable. Now, due to the introduction of the new measure, we have reduced much of the original volatility in the time series $X_{t}$. So when we estimate the variance of this new time series $Y_{t}$, the estimate will be biased downward.

We would like to get an unbiased estimator of the variance that reflects the volatility of $X_{t}$. Now, according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation#Effect_of_autocorrelation_(serial_correlation)), we can calculate our unbiased estimate of the variance using the provided equation. It also states in a caveat that we need the **analytical** expression for the ACF function and it cannot be estimated from the biased data.

**This leads me to my question**, is it correct that my process $Y_{t}$ is a $\text{MA}(11)$ process

$$Y_{t}=\mu+\epsilon_{t}-\sum_{k=1}^{11}\theta_{k}\epsilon_{t+k}$$

and that, as a result, I can calculate the analytical ACF for my data given that I know the parameters of my process are all equal. Is this intuition correct?

**Additionally**, is the analytical ACF of this $\text{MA}(12)$ process

$$\begin{align}
\rho(\tau)=\frac{\gamma(\tau)}{\gamma(0)}&=\frac{\sigma^{2}\sum_{j=0}^{12-|\tau|}\theta_{j}\theta_{j+|\tau|}}{\sigma^{2}\sum_{j=0}^{12}\theta_{j}\theta_{j}}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{12-|\tau|}\theta^{2}}{\sum_{j=0}^{12}\theta^{2}}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{12-|\tau|}}{\sum_{j=0}^{12}}\\
&=\frac{13-|\tau|}{13},\quad\quad\quad |\tau|\le 12
\end{align}$$

correct?

Comment: If you look at your right hand side carefully, you will note that the subscript of $\epsilon_k$ is independent of $t$, which is not what you want!

Comment: @jbowman Thanks, I'm still not sure my notation is exactly correct. Does my intuition for solving the problem seem correct?

Comment: Given that it's a forward average, I think the subscript $t+k$ would be correct.  But yes, given that minor caveat, your intuition is (also) correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data are independent with the same mean and different variances then you can write $X_t = \mu + b_t \epsilon_t$ and

\begin{align*}
Y_t &= \frac{1}{12}\sum_{k=0}^{11} X_{t+k}\\
&= \frac{1}{12}\sum_{k=0}^{11} \mu + b_{t+k} \epsilon_{t+k} \\
&= \mu + \sum_{k=0}^{11} \theta_k  \epsilon_{t+k}
\end{align*}
where  $\theta_k = b_{t+k}/12$.

If your data was from a causal linear process to begin with, then you can write your $X_t$ as a moving average process (who knows what the order is, though), and your $Y_t$ will always be a moving average process. However, it will not necessarily be of order 12. If you start with a linear process, and you filter it (which is what you're doing), you will always have a linear process as a result.

### Edit

To answer your new question, I will assume your data are iid and I will shift the time index for $Y$ forward, which means 
$$
Y_t = \mu + \theta\epsilon_t + \sum_{i=1}^{11} \theta\epsilon_{t-i} = \mu + W_t + \sum_{i=1}^{11} W_{t-i},
$$
which is a non-invertible MA(11) process.

\begin{align*}
\gamma_Y(h) &= \text{Cov}(Y_{t+h},Y_t)\\
&= \text{Cov}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{11} W_{t+h-i} ,\sum_{j=0}^{11} W_{t-j}\right)\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{11}\sum_{j=0}^{11}\gamma_W(j+h-i)\\
&= \theta^2(12-|h|)
\end{align*}
which means $\rho_Y(h) = (12-|h|)/12$.

Comment: My goal was to calculate the analytical ACF for the $Y_{t}$ series. Are you saying I can't actually do that because I don't know the order $q$?

Comment: @StatsPlease no it's doable, but you need to be clear about what your assumptions about $X_t$ are

Comment: So under the assumption that $X_{t}$ are iid I can say that the order $q=12$?

Comment: @StatsPlease yes, if they are independent AND IDENTICAL, then it simplifies the situation a little bit. In that case, $b_t$ are all the same, and you have an MA(12) process where all the $\theta$ are the same. Be aware that there is a convention, though, that people will write down an MA(1) process with a leading coefficient of $1$ (e.g. $Y_t = \epsilon_t  + \theta_1 \epsilon_{t-1}$), so you might need to make an adjustment.